# Array with degree of curvature

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to use an array to do this where I can make adjustments to the curvature by changing the angle between the cubes. Is there any way of doing this with the array modifier to control that angle? I have tried several of the Array tutorials without any real success, thanks for any suggestions.
[image: Cube Array separation angle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use object offset in the array modifier and then rotate the offsetting object (and then hide it if you don't want it visible in the scene)

[image]

Comment: This was VERY helpful and does exactly what i need, thank you for the help BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Array + simple deform will let you change the angle. Not sure if this would serve your purpose though as this would change the shape of the cube.

[image: Array + deform]

Comment: This would be great if it didn't deform the cube, thank you for the help B